# Prevent gem A from overriding methods of unrelated gem B

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

For some time, [xml-simple](http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/) gem had been working for me just fine (indirectly, through another gem).

But lately I had to install Amazon S3 gem also. Amazon guys had decided that xml-simple wasn't cool enough, so they supplied a replacement: 'faster-xml-simple'. And they also decided that everybody wants to use their code now, so they did this:

```
class XmlSimple # :nodoc:
  def self.xml_in(*args)
    FasterXmlSimple.xml_in *args
  end
end
```

But two gems largely differ in behaviour and options. And now, each time I call `XmlSimple.xml_in`, I go to Amazon's version.

Is there a way to stop gem A (amazon S3) from overriding methods of gem B (xml-simple)? Or make Amazon's changes seen only to Amazon's gems? E.g., when deployed on Heroku, it all works just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the phenomenon is called monkeypatching.

Comment: @Andrew Do you mean, we have to learn to live with it?

Comment: I don't know - I'm just mentioning the concept so that it's easier to google about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby has open classes, which means that anybody can modify any class at any time. There's no way to prevent that. And problems like the one you are describing are exactly the reason why every manual, every tutorial, every course, every FAQ teaches *not* to do that.

Over the last 10 years or so, there has been talk of adding *selector namespaces* to Ruby 2.0, to provide lexically scoped monkey patching. More recently, matz has set his sights on [*classboxes*](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/classboxes/). It looks very likely that Ruby 2.0 will provide classboxes to limit the scope of monkey patching, but until then, your best bet is to file a bug with the author of that library.